# Wordpress export posts for own system

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm moving a site over that is currently setup in wordpress. I've not got a great knowledge on how WP works but the database all makes sense to me. I've built a custom blogging engine for the new site but I need to transfer all the old posts into the new site.

Before I go writing a script to loop through each posts then grab the image url etc and then match that up to the columns in my own database is there anything that exists already? I can't imagine I'm the first to do this!

Also - am I right in thinking that the image(s) for the post are `_wp_attached_file` with the corresponding `post_id` in the `wp_postmeta` table?

I've tagged this with php for Wordpress but happy for scripts in Python or RoR too if they exist.

Thanks

Comment: Is the standard wordpress export not detailed enough? I find this a very handy tool: http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/

Comment: Justus - that is perfect. You should put this as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the standard wordpress export not detailed enough? I find this a very handy tool: http://en.support.wordpress.com/export

Comment: Thanks. Much easier to just parse the XML after that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-export-all-post-information-excel-format/) that imports your posts into a CSV file. It would be simpler to write a parser for that, I think - instead of writing a script to query the WP DB